# Audio Recorder get noise level in decibal

Tags: android, recorder

I am trying to fetch noise level of recorded audio in decibals. I am using following code but it is not giving the correct output

```
byte[] audioData = new byte[bufferSize];
recorder.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(audioData);
int sampleSize = bb.getInt();
```

now if I log sampleSize then it gives very huge value like 956318464

Can anybody tell how to get correct noise level in decibals.

Comment: What do you mean by "noise level"? Are you trying to measure the amount of noise in a recording (e.g. the Signal-to-Noise-Ratio)? You could probably achieve some sort of measurement of stationary noise by analyzing the energy within certain frequency bands, but for dynamic noise I doubt you could get good results without having a reference signal. If you're trying to calculate the Sound Pressure Level... well, you've already got the signal's linear amplitude (that's what you get when reading from the recorder) and that's what you'd base the calculation on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off-  decibels is a ratio.  You can't just get decibels, you need to compare the volume to a baseline measurement.  So the real equation in terms of amplitude is

db= 10* log10(amplitude/baseline_amplitude);

If you're recording the audio now, to get the amplitude use MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude.  For a baseline amplitude, measure the expected background noise.

Comment: what will be formula of baseline_amplitude?

Comment: You need to measure for it-  its the amplitude of the background noise.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int calculatePowerDb(short[] sdata, int off, int samples)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double sqsum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++)
        {
            final long v = sdata[off + i];
            sum += v;
            sqsum += v * v;
        }
        double power = (sqsum - sum * sum / samples) / samples;

        power /= MAX_16_BIT * MAX_16_BIT;

        double result = Math.log10(power) * 10f + FUDGE;
        return (int)result;
    }
    private static final float MAX_16_BIT = 32768;
private static final float FUDGE = 0.6f;
```

its works fine this methode